Sample space when two identical dice are thrown simultaneously
When two different dice are thrown the sample space is 36 {i.e. (1,1),(1,2),(2,1).... and so on } i get this.
But if the dice thrown are identical then order of face appearing on the dice wouldn't matter and (1,2) and (2,1) on the dice would appear to be the same to the observer . Shouldn't this reduce the sample size to twenty one
I am unable to understand why the sample size still remains 36 even with identical die . Can someone please provide the correct explanation and where i am going wrong .

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803493/chevalier-de-mere-paradox-with-game-with-three-dice

I would say the sample space is smaller too, but the outcomes are not equiprobable.

$21$ samples with equiprobability is a set of dominoes on $0\dots5$.

The reason to define the sample space with 36 elements is such that the probability of an event $A$ can then be defined as: $$\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac{\text{Number of elements in A}}{\text{Number elements in sample space}}$$

The reason we use a sample space of  36 ordered pairs, instead of 21 unordered pairs, is because of independence. If you want the two dice to be independent, they need to be distinguishable.
We say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if, for all possible values $x$ that $X$ can take, and all possible values $y$ that $Y$ can take,
$$
P(X=x\text{ and }Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)
$$
This assumption is necessary to model real world dice; we have done statistical tests, and see real dice obey the above law.
In order to even state the definition of independence, we need to have given labels to the two dice, $X$ and $Y$. This leads to a probability space of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, where $x$ is the result of $X$ and $y$ is the result of $Y$.
As a consequence of independence, and because the dice are fair, we learn that all ordered pairs are equally likely. For all possible pairs of values $(x,y)$,
$$
P((X,Y)=(x,y))=P(X=x)P(Y=y)=(1/6)(1/6)=1/36
$$
Since all 36 ordered pairs are equally likely, they make a convenient sample space. Remember that if you choose your sample space so that all outcomes are equally likely, then you can calculate the probability of an event by counting outcomes: $P(E)=|E|/(\text{# total outcomes})$. This gives another reason to use 36 ordered pairs; it leads to convenient calculation.
